# Como percorrer um Objeto e filtrar este objeto?

Tags: javascript, foreach, objetos

eu estou tentando percorrer um objeto e apos isso, filtrar o mesmo.

Eu estou usando este codigo, porem nao está funcionando.

Alguem poderia me ajudar e se possivel explicar o codigo ?

```js
const objeto = { 
idade: 20,
idade:20,
idade:21};

const funcao = parametros => parametros === 20;

const funcaooriginal = objeto.forEach(funcao);

console.log(funcaooriginal);
```

Comment: Seu objeto não faz sentido. Ele possui três vezes o mesmo atributo com valores distintos. Tem certeza que você não tem um *array* de objetos? Algo como `[{idade: 20}, {idade: 21}, ...]`?

Comment: Na verdade sim, era pra ser:

e cada idade, ter um nome

Comment: Então edite a pergunta e coloque o código correto, por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o [**`Array.prototype.filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

```js
const lista = [
  { idade: 20, nome: 'Fulano' },
  { idade: 20, nome: 'Ciclano' },
  { idade: 21, nome: 'Beltrano' }
];

let filtrado = lista.filter((item) => item.idade == 20);
console.log(filtrado);
```